# Can I turn an array into an array of Promises?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, promise, bluebird

I am using `bluebird`, if that matters. I have an array of objects:

```
a = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

I want to use promises to iterate over each of them and then do some processing.

```
a.each (obj) ->
  doStuff obj
.then (objArray) ->
  moreStuff()
```

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

```
var addedFilesTree;

addedFilesTree = [1, 2, 3];

Promise.map(addedFilesTree).then(function(addedFileTree) {
  return console.log(addedFileTree);
});
```

is my actual code. This returns an error:

```
Possibly unhandled TypeError: fn must be a function

    See http://goo.gl/916lJJ
```

Comment: Yes, this is CoffeeScript

Comment: Your actual code is erroring because it's missing the `doStuff` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Promise.map a, (obj) ->
  doStuff obj
.then (objArray) ->
  moreStuff()
```

Comment: Does `.map` do things concurrently?

Comment: This returns an error:

`Possibly unhandled TypeError: fn must be a function

    See http://goo.gl/916lJJ`

Comment: @Shamoon The signature is `Promise.map a, (obj) ->`, you did not even pass any function.

Comment: oops! Thanks. #DumbMistake